# Dispatching different actions with multiple axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a get method sending different requests and i want to dispatch an action for any request i send.

See the relevant code

```
export function getTeamsStats(league, team, type) {
  return function(dispatch) {

    let url1 = "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/891/490/2020-01-09"
    let url2 = "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/891/490/2020-02-09"
    let url3 = "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/891/490/2020-03-09"

    let urlArray = [url1,url2,url3]

    let promiseArray = urlArray.map(url => axios.get(url));

    const api = true;

    if (api) {
      return axios({
        method: "get",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": ""
        }
      })
      .all(promiseArray)
      .then(res => {
        const {
          matchsPlayed: { home: teamsMatchsPlayedHome, away: teamsMatchsPlayedAway},
          wins: { home: teamsStatsWinHome, away: teamsStatsWinAway },
          draws: { home: teamsStatsDrawHome, away: teamsStatsDrawAway },
          loses: { home: teamsStatsLoseHome, away: teamsStatsLoseAway }
        } = res.data.api.statistics.matchs;
        const teamStats = {
          teamsMatchsPlayedHome,
          teamsMatchsPlayedAway,
          teamsStatsWinHome,
          teamsStatsWinAway,
          teamsStatsDrawHome,
          teamsStatsDrawAway,
          teamsStatsLoseHome,
          teamsStatsLoseAway
         }
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStat(teamStats, type));
```

For any of these 3 urls i want to do this dispatch `dispatch(receivedTeamsStat(teamStats, type));`

I was able to do the same `dispatch` with just a single url request and get the sates but now i do not know how to achieve the same thing doing the `dispatch` for each url.

Comment: You can use `localstorage` to store and retrieve the data

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I think he said he doesn't want to use local storage

Comment: I prefer not using it, but my confusion is basically when i select a team i need to put a lot of get call sequentially with my parameter date, how can i make this more dymanic with the parameter date? I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic may help you. You can use `forEach` in `.then()`

```
.then( res => res.forEach( result => dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload:  result.data}))
```

Inside:

```
...

if (api) {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": ""
    }
  })
  .all(promiseArray)
  .then( res => {
        ...

        res.forEach( result => dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload:  result.data}))

        ...
  })

  ...
```

Comment: thanks Mohammed, do you mind to make it more specific to my code snippet, i am now trying to implement this logic

Comment: I do like this => https://gist.github.com/Mannaio/1945b7c5c00434316cfa0ea27ca3d483, i can dispatch the action but i can not see the states in the component, it is getting better tough

Comment: Your question was how dispatch an action for any request. I'm glad this logic helped، So accept it as an answer. And as for the not see the states in the component, Please check `console.log(teamStats)` in `.then() `

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a state

```
this.state={
  myArray:[]
}
```

For each api call, you can modify the state as follows

```
get('URL').then((res)=>{
    //Some extra code here to create object to be appended and maybe to check if the get was successfull
    let x = this.state.myArray;
    x.push(object);
    this.setState(x);
})
```

As for date,

Comment: Ok, does it makes sense if i make this for 30 get calls more and less? It can be a bit redundant or there is a better way?

Comment: @Koala7 I didn't get where the redundancy is coming from. There is no extra space or variables being used. Each time the API is called, the array is directly being modified.

Comment: I want to accept your answer because of the time spent, i have reproduced my exact case here https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bhabha-fv152?file , can you show me how to start there in order to create this Array state dynamically? The relevant code is in action/index.js in when i do the getTeamsStats where i have to add the parameter date,  i open a bounty for it

Comment: @Koala7 Sorry. Didn't realize you were using functional instead of class components. However, you can still use react hooks (which I assume you know since you have used them in your code). In the component that calls `getTeamsStats()`, create a hook `[leagues, setLeagues]` and initialize it to a blank array. Then, pass `setLeagues()` as  another parameter to the function. So your params will look something like `getTeamsStats(league, team, type,setLeague)`. You can then call the `setLeagues` function inside `getTeamsStats` function.

Comment: This is already in place, i pass the the leagueId when i select the team, what i think i have to do maybe, making all the get request with the the date parameter and create an hook [dates, setDates] passing and setting the stats  for each request in the array so i can have dates with the same data structure i want for che charts but i think the code can ne so unnecessary long

Comment: I have edited the question, i made it more specific and easier to understand